# How to avoid the unwanted <p></p> tags while getting the post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get the data from a post using the following snippet:

```
<div class="marquee-container row marquee-row">
<?php
$post = get_post(415);
if(isset($post->post_status) && $post->post_status == 'publish') {
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
}
?>
</div>
```

But when I inspect the element, I found some unwanted `<p></p>` tags which are unnecessarily introducing gaps.

```
<div class="marquee-container row marquee-row">
<p> </p>
<div class="some-class">Content from the post</div>
<p></p>
</div>
```

How to avoid this unwanted tags ?
**Note:** This tags are not being inserted to table, being introduce while trying to get the post.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Instead of using the_content, you can use get_the_content if you dont want any formatting.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check that content from admin side in `text` tab(Where you add the contents for page or post)? If you have pressed Enter key then it will take that as `<p></p>` tag in content.

Remove blank spaces from editor if it is not necessary.

Comment: Yes I have checked for the extra spaces, more over I have verified it in the table and there is no `<p></p>` tags there.